# Trying to create something from chart.js

Tags: javascript, frameworks, chart.js

Total noob here. Wanted to include a JS library that wasn't jQuery. Saw [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/), and it looked cool. However, I am having a hard time getting the doughnut chart to show up. Why? Anyways, here are my steps and the respective code behind them:

1. I went to the Chart.js GitHub, copy+pasta'd the chart.js file, saved it as my own.
   (https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js)
2. Include chart.js in html.
   `<script type='text/javascript' src='chart.js'></script>`
3. Create an HTML canvass element that is 150x150.
   `<canvas id="myChart" width="150" height="150"></canvas>`
4. Create testChart.js file.

   ```
   var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

   var data = [
       {
           value: 300,
           color: "#F7464A",
           highlight: "#FF5A5E",
           label: "alpha"
       },
       {
           value: 50,
           color: "#46BFBD",
           highlight: "#5AD3D1",
           label: "bravo"
       },
       {
           value: 100,
           color: "#FDB45C",
           highlight: "#FFC870",
           label: "charlie"
       }
   ];
   };

   var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx[1]).Doughnut(data);
   ```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org) doughnut is not showing up because your code is causing a JavaScript error. Unfortunately, Chart.js also depends on [jQuery](http://jquery.com)... So you'll need to import that too.

```
}; // <--- this shouldn't be here

var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx[1]).Doughnut(data);
```

Removing the `};` should fix it.

In the future, you can use debugging tools as indicated in the w3 schools article on [debugging JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp).

Here is a working version of your code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r32ba8qa/5/)